# How to get session time duration on a page using php?

Tags: php

I am trying to get the time spent on  the pages in my site.
I need to get that the time duration of a session for implementing some features.
How I can take that?.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Time spent with a page open isn't necessarily the time that the user is actively using the page.  This information may be meaningless.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Google analytics can answer your questions, but as Nigel says, it may not be useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [this](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) Github repository this could help you some of its features are listed below

- Sessions
- Page Views (hits on routes)
- Users (logged users)
- Devices (computer, smartphone, tablet...)
- Languages (preference, language range)
- User Devices (by, yeah, storing a cookie on each device)
- Browsers (Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer...)
- Events

This tracker provides a lot of infomative information about user interaction of page like what was clicked by whom. It also stores session information of user
although it does not fully address the requirements you want because it stores sessions and events occured by user but does not tell how much time he spent
but **You can evaluate almost interactive time that user spent on individual pages**
by calculating the sum of all difference between all the events occured by user on single page e.g he cilcked combobox typed some thing then wait and then again clicked some thing else